# Create a tsv file from MySQL table. Add more imaginary headers

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I have a MySQL table, from which I create tsv and csv files. I want to create the tsv file whilst adding imaginary headers to the file. I already use the MySQL column headers as the headers for the file, but I need to add extra imaginary headers not in the MySQL table. My current code creates the file, but I do not know how to go about adding the imaginary headers.

It outputs

```
name    age address
Daniel  24  Carlifornia
Jane    22  New York
```

I want to output

```
name    age address option1 option2
Daniel  24  Carlifornia anything    anything
Jane    22  New York    anything    anything
```

Here's my code:

```
@chmod($export_tsv, 0777);
$fe = @fopen($export_tsv."/export.tsv", "w+");
if($fe){           
    $somecontent = "";
    //$somecontent = "header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')";
    $fields_count = 0;

    // fields headers
    $db->query($sql_view);
    if($row = $db->fetchAssoc()){
        foreach($row as $key => $val){
            if($fields_count++ > 0) $somecontent .= "\t";
            // mysql column headers here
            $somecontent .= $key;
        }
    }
    $somecontent .= "\r\n"; 

    $db->query($sql_view);
    while($row = $db->fetchAssoc()){
        $fields_count = 0;
        foreach($row as $key => $val){
            if($fields_count++ > 0) $somecontent .= "\t";
            //my own special code start
            $val = str_replace("\n","", $val);
            $val = str_replace("\r","", $val);
            $val = str_replace("\t","", $val);

            $val = stripslashes($val);                    
            $val = str_replace("chr(13)","", $val);
            //my own special code end

            $somecontent .= $val;              
        }
        $somecontent .= "\r\n"; 
    }
    utf8_encode($somecontent);
    $somecontent = mb_convert_encoding($somecontent, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");

    // write some content to the opened file.
   if (fwrite($fe, utf8_encode($somecontent)) == FALSE)
       echo 'file_writing_error'." (export.tsv)"; 
   fclose($fe);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `AS` keyword in your SQL query?

```
select something AS `new column name` FROM some_table
```

Comment: thanks. was looking at an opportunity to get it printed on the fly without changing or using a select statement from code

Comment: This is how you "rename" result columns on the fly in a query and I thought this was what you meant by imaginary columns. Especially since the value of that column can be anything really. What is it that you want to do really? Could you maybe update your question with an example of what you currently output and what you want to output?